# Labels being acessed from other classes?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, label, global

I have two classes here and I want the label from the parent class to be available in the child class. I've tried making the label a global variable but that doesn't seem to work either unless I'm doing something wrong (I've only been using Python for two weeks). Here's the code.

```
from tkinter import *

class Parent_Class(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_labels()

    def create_labels(self):
        self.label_1 = Label(self)
        self.label_1["text"] = "I'm in the Parent Class."
        self.label_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

class Child_Class():

    def __init__(self):
        self.change_label()

    def change_label(self):
        label_1["text"] = "I'm in the Child Class."

window = Tk()
window.title("Label Test")
window.geometry("250x250")
app = Parent_Class(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never directly change a widget outside of a class that creates it. If you choose to modify that original class, you end up having to change two or more classes. Instead, you give the class with the label an interface that other classes can use. You *can* directly access the label, but it results in what is called "tight coupling"

Regardless, the key to making it work is that you have to pass to the child a reference to the parent.

It works something like this, using an interface. Again, you could directly access `parent.label` instead of calling an interface, but that's generally a bad idea.

```
class Parent_Class(...):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.label = Label(...)
        ...
    def set_label(self, string):
        self.label.configure(text=string)


class Child_Class(...):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.parent = parent
        ...
    def change_label(self):
        self.parent.set_label("I'm in the Child Class")
        # of, if tight coupling is acceptable to you:
        # self.parent.label.configure(text="I'm in the Child Class")

...
p = Parent_Class(...)
c = Child_Class(parent=p)
```

Comment: I've tried implementing the changes to my current code but it doesn't seem to work. There are no errors but the label will not change.